# Symfony2 FOSJsRoutingBundle: how to apply filters

Tags: symfony

I would like to know how to apply filters with `Routing.generate()`.

In my template i can do the following:

```
var remotePathPlayerSearch = "{{ path('_api_get_players_search', {searchterm: '%QUERY', limit: 5}) |url_decode|raw }}";
```

The equivalent in JS is

```
Routing.generate('_api_get_players_search', {'searchterm':'%QUERY', 'limit': 5}, true);
```

Now how can i apply `url_decode` and `raw` to the url generation?

Comment: Are you creating the JS one in a JS file? I mean where do you use it and generate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Using FOSJsRoutingBundle the URL is generated via JavaScript on client machine, not on the server.